# symbol for degree celsius in memoir

Tags: macros, symbols, degrees

I am using memoir for writing thesis.

I have some issues in using symbol degree. The packages I am using are as below.

```
%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % interpret input as unicode
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % choose main font encoding (Cork)
\usepackage{textcomp}       % additional symbols using companion encoding TS1
\usepackage{gensymb}        % provides macro \degree which works in text and math

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}



\usepackage{ulem} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{booktabs}



%FOR CHEMISTRY
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
%%chemistry formulas
\usepackage{bpchem}
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{bpchem}
\usepackage{chemmacros}



%FOR FIGURE 
\usepackage{mwe}    % loads »blindtext« and »graphicx«
\usepackage{subfig}
```

When I used command like 40{`\degree`}, I get an error message saying `Command \degree already defined. \newcommand\degree{}`

Why is `\degree` is not working?

Can I get some help?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The only way you can get that error is if you define it and it already exists, or you load a package that tries to define it when it already exists. Can you provide a more clear [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your problem? It's not clear from your current code snippet.

Comment: You have `siunitx` in preamble. Why you do not use its facility for Celsius degree? For example `\celsius` or longer `\degreeCelsius`. This packages also define macro `\degree`, which probably make your troubles. Try to remove package `gensymb` (if it is inserted only for degree symbol).

Comment: Dear Zarko, I commented 'gensymb' and tried with commands like  \celsius and  \degreeCelsius separately. In every attempt I get message like "Undefined control sequence ..."

Comment: @Vijay if you want that people are notified you need to preced there names with an @. Did you use it like `\SI{4}{\celsius}` or `\si{\celsius}`? Unrelated: why do load both `usepackage[T1]{fontenc} ` and `usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}`? Delete the one with `OT1`. Also loading both `mhchem` *and* `chemformula` seems redundant (they're alternatives for the same task). Choose one of them. Also you're loading `bpchem` twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really answer, however in comment I can not show the code result. As already mentioned in Werner comments, you have defined macro `degree` twice. I suspect, that ones is in package `gensymb` and ones in `siunitx. So I suggest to comment the first one and use`siunitx` syntax. It doesn't allowe to use in it defined macros directly in text (I anticipated, that you try their in that way), but together in numbers as show the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
\begin{preview}% <---------------------------------
Today expected maximal temperature is between \SI{24}{\celsius} and \SI{28}{\degree}C. Late afternoon will become colder with only \SI{11}{\degreeCelsius}. Just use \verb+\degree+ in text doesn't work.
\end{preview}% <---------------------------------
    \end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Siunitx syntax care about for nice looking of values with units and also has other benefits. For more particular help, you need to extend your code snippet to workable example, that we can copy and test it.

Comment: This works fine: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gensymb,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI{14}{\celsius}
\end{document}`

Comment: @clemments,  I don't know gensymb package, so I express only suspect. Also I haven't installed it, so I can not test this.

Comment: Dear @clemments, thanks for indicating my mistakes and showed the ritght way to fix this problem. Now it is working properly.

Comment: @Vijay I only get notified when you spell my name correctly :)

Comment: @clemens . . sorry. Misspelled ur name.